# My jQuery listener won't recognize my trigger click

Tags: jquery, triggers

I am trying to get a dialog box to pop up if somebody forgets to fill out a field on a form using C# and aspx.  My trigger is in my header and looks like this.

```
 function CheckSalesman() {
   alert("Alert!!!!!!!!!");
   $('#opener').trigger('click');

 }
```

This clicks a hidden button.  The button has the id opener.  The listener I have is in body of my code.  This is used to trigger the dialog box.

```
 $("#opener").click(function () {
     alert("OpenDialog!");
     stopSubmit();

     $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
```

The reason it is down here is because right above the javascript tag that this is in, is where my dialog box gets established.  I have tried have the listener in the header but it does not work up there.  Under were the dialog box is established is the only place I can get it to work.

I have tried to move the the trigger underneath the listener and then the trigger function will never run.  The trigger function is called by a aspx label having the code below inserted into its .text attribute.

```
<script>CheckSalesman()</script>
```

I have also tried moving both the listener and trigger to the header, and then to the body, and then filled where they both were.  None of this has worked.  I changed the id of the hidden button hoping that might do something but once again, nothing.  I do see the alert in the trigger but not in the listener.

I don't understand why this isn't working.  From what myself and the guy I am working on this with know, this should work.

Comment: Is missing the `$` in `("#opener").click(function ()` a typo? And the link with id `opener` is initiated when you trigger the function?

Comment: Is the hidden button a `ASP.NET` control

Comment: no the button is not  and the  missing $ is a typo sorry.

Comment: $('#opener').trigger('click'); is run when the function CheckSalesman() is run

Comment: Is `#dialog` created dynamically?

Comment: no it is hard coded in like this    <div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title"></div>

Comment: Do you see both the `"Alert!!!!!!!!!"` and `"OpenDialog!"` alerts?

Comment: No just the "Alert!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"

Comment: Right before your hook, add an alert so you can see the order in which things are happening.

Comment: Actually, this sounds like you might have a javascript syntax error somewhere on the page, or malformed HTML since moving the trigger around causes it to no longer work.  I don't think we are going to be able to help you any more without seeing the actual html that's getting rendered.

Comment: Are you doing any kind of AJAX on the page (jQuery or UpdatePanel), or manipulating the DOM where you might accidentally be removing the hook?

Comment: no I am not doing any of those things.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code as you've posted it.  The problem lies elsewhere.  Here's a jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/dsyUa/

1. Is your label set to not HtmlEncode the text? Otherwise, your script
   tags will not be interpreted correctly.
2. Is both the function and hook code above the call code? If not, they
   don't exist yet, and can't possibly execute.
3. Are you including the jQuery library on the page prior to the hook
   code?
4. Do you have the hook code wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function(){
   ... }` block? If so, that won't execute until after the page has
   loaded, and your check is happening WHILE the page is loading.
5. Does the dialog library require the page to be ready before you can
   call it? Try changing your label text to:

---

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    CheckSalemen();
  },5000);
});
</script>
```

You can tweak it later, but this basically waits for the page to be ready, and then an additional 5 seconds before it tries to do the check.

Comment: 1.  This parts works fine.  The function in the script tags does run.    2.  The function and trigger above the listener.                       3. yes the jQuery library is a the top of the page.                    4. No it is not.                                                        5. My page loads and the user inputs some info and when they click a submit button, the check is run and if it fails then my checkSalesman function is run.

Comment: Here's another jsfiddle with everything you've described, but I'm calling .dialog with no parameters since it hasn't been initialized yet, and stopSubmit call removed since I don't have one: http://jsfiddle.net/dsyUa/3/